# Not able to understand this prototype concept

Tags: javascript, prototype

I was going through an  [article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Object_prototypes)` and I came across this code ,
where it was explaining about prototype, and how it works.
What I want is , what does this sentence  mean with respect to the code.

> This code creates a Date object, then walks up the prototype chain, logging the prototypes. It shows us that the prototype of myDate is a Date.prototype object, and the prototype of that is Object.prototype

```
const myDate = new Date();
let object = myDate;

do {  
  object = Object.getPrototypeOf(object);
  console.log(object);

} while (object);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s actually quite straightforward:

```js
const myDate = new Date();   // Create a Date object.
let object = myDate;

do {  
  object = Object.getPrototypeOf(object); // Find the object’s prototype.
  console.log(object);                    // Print to the log.
} while (object);            // Repeat (finding prototypes’ prototypes)
                             // as long as there are prototypes to be found.
```

So, we will find out that the object’s prototype *also* has a prototype. That’s the chain the excerpt talks about.